# FPDF add a hidden data in pdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I would like to add a simple hidden data (could be comment or something) for generate pdf file through fpdf library. I need simple protection of authenticity, that this file has been generated through my application .

Thanks for answers

Comment: *that this file has been generated through my application* - so you want to leave some fingerprint in the file by which you can later recognize that the document has been created by your service? Or shall everybody easy be enabled to see that? And should this marker break if someone else manipulates the file? Or should it be as sticky as possible?

Answer (score 4):

Option 1 :
You can set the pdf with below.  (the properties only viewable at pdf reader)

```
$pdf->SetTitle("Any Title");
$pdf->SetAuthor("Any Author");
$pdf->SetSubject("Any Subject");
$pdf->SetCreator("Any Creator");
```

I think you need extend your FPDF class to [FPDFP](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script37.php) (Protection), If not will be able to change the setting.

Option 2 :
using [Watermark](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script9.php) class extension.

Option 3 :
generate some non-understand wording as your pdf signature at bottom page. If you don't want print out at the paper, set the text color. (look like cheat way but simple)

```
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);//Set to White color
$pdf->Cell(20,10,'onlyme_understand_signature',1,1,'C');
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);//Set to Black color
```

Comment: Using any of these methods, you can add an HMAC signature, that can't be forged even if someone understands what it means.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way to add metadata (XMP) data using FPDF. TCPDF can do it:

```
TCPDF::setExtraXMP($someCustomString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this that I see (it's far from waterproof but adding something to XMP also isn't waterproof) is to set the creator of the file correctly using:

> SetCreator(string creator [, boolean isUTF8])

This will allow you to have a specific string for who created the file which you could easily test for later. As most PDF consumers leave the creator string alone once it's there, this might be good enough for your purposes.